# How do I stop R from prepending X to my numeric column labels?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with numeric column labels, for example:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

When I load this data into a variable in R using `as.matrix(read.table("myfile", sep=",", header=TRUE)` and print the resulting matrix, the column headers have been prepended with X, and this extra character appears in plots and the like:

```
     X1     X2     X3
[1,]  1      2      3
[2,]  4      5      6
[3,]  7      8      9
```

How can I stop this behaviour?

Comment: I suspect you have not comprehended the adverse consequences of this path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supply `check.names=FALSE` to `read.table`.

Be aware that when `data.frame`s have non-standard names such as this any reference to their columns must be surrounded with tick marks, e.g.

```
my.df <- read.table(text='1,2,3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9', header=TRUE, sep=',', check.names=FALSE)

my.df$`1`
with(my.df, `1`)
attach(k)
`1`
```

Also, calls to `transform`, such as `transform(my.df,`1`=1:3)`, will replace the column names with their standardized forms (`X1`, `X2`, `X3`) because `transform` calls `data.frame()` with its default arguments.

Setting `check.names=FALSE`, while useful in some very particular situations, will allow duplicate column names and non syntactic names, which could cause any number of problems later on. Be cautious when using this.

`data.frame()` uses `check.names=TRUE` by default because in many contexts R tries to interpret the column names of a data frame as variables in their own right; if the column names are not syntactically valid names (see `?make.names`), or protected with back-ticks as described above, then errors will occur in these contexts.

Comment: @mplourrde: I think it would be responsible of you to describe the consequences of this choice.

Comment: @DWin Please feel free to add anything I've missed.